# Crear subdominios y emails noreply desde mi app

Tags: api, email, dns, subdominio, panel-de-administracion

Cómo hago para administrar mis dominios y correos asociados a esos dominios desde una api?, o sea, para ser más directo, yo quiero crear subdominios y direcciones de correos tipo no-reply para mis clientes de modo dinámico desde mi app, desde mi backend de manera que cuando ellos se registren tengan su propio dominio y email personalizado solo para enviar correos pero partiendo de mi propio dominio principal tal como lo hace muchos servicios para darte un subdominio como Blogger, WordPress, GitHub, etc, ejemplo crear para mis clientes de modo dinámico **[ProyectoDelCliente].[UsuarioDelCliente].miapp.com** y **no-reply@[ProyectoDelCliente].[UsuarioDelCliente].miapp.com** o **[ProyectoDelCliente]@[UsuarioDelCliente].miapp.com**
Y el correo no-reply que le daría a mis clientes sería como es lógico para enviar emails personalizados de ellos, sin bandeja de entrada.
Cómo puedo hacer todo esto?

Comment: Depende de muchas cosas, pero si usas por ejemplo ISPConfig en tu server, tienes disponible una API para crear subdominios, correos y demás, supongo que Plesk tendrá la suya y CPanel la suya, si tu servidor no usa ninguno de estos, tendrás que hacer la API tu mismo con scrpits.

Comment: O sea depende en donde yo haya comprado mi dominio según las opciones que me dé mi proveedor.. mmm yo necesitaría entonces un buen servicio de cloud que me incluya ya un api para eso. Estaba pensando Google Cloud pero no he podido dar con la seguridad de que ellos me permitan hacer eso. Google tiene varios apis pero no estoy seguro todavía de poder hacer lo que quiero y también Google cloud es gigante tiene muchos servicios que no necesito por ahora. cPanel creo tiene un api para eso pero no estoy seguro que lo tenga como un apiRest pues cPanel es con PHP y yo no uso PHP

Comment: Si, depende de tu proveedor de hosting, yo para ahorrarme problemas, contrato hostings que sean mantenidos por mi e instalo todo desde cero como yo quiero, la versión de GNU/Linux que quiero y el resto de paquetes igual y como no, suelo poner ispconfig.

Comment: Por cierto, si solo quieres el correo es mucho más sencillo, pues solo necesitas un correo recogetodo y desde imap, creas un cliente en php o como gustes para que los usuarios accedan a su correo dependiendo del user, aunque eso no tiene en cuenta el tema de los subdominios.

Comment: Gracias por tus respuestas. Creo que sí sería mejor montar mi propio hosting con servidor dns propio también pero eso conlleva más configuraciones a bajo nivel de la que no estoy muy bien familiarizado. En todo caso estoy chequeando y estudiando otras posibilidades a ver qué me sale más económico y a la vez menos enredado de configurar y mantener. Estoy revisando Google Cloud DNS un poco más al detalle. Lo cierto es que todavía tengo dudas técnicas y de definiciones etc etc. Lo bueno de Google cloud es que tiene API y además clientes para NodeJS y Go que es lo que pienso usar en el backend

Comment: Aún así sigo investigando la mejor opción en cuanto a dificultad de administración y precio. Creo que GoDaddy también tiene API. En fin, sigo indagando